# Access denied error when curl'ing S3 object from pre-signed url

Tags: python, curl, amazon-s3

This is the script which I wrote for downloading object from S3 via a pre-signed url:

```
import boto3
import os


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '<>'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '<>'
region = '<>'

session = boto3.Session(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region_name = region)
s3 = session.client('s3')
url = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket': '<>', 'Key': '<>.json'}, ExpiresIn = 100)

print url

os.system('curl ' + url)
```

From this, I am able to get the url, but the `os.system` command is giving me the following error:

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>...</RequestId><HostId>...</HostId></Error>
```

But, when I directly try the url in my browser, it is downloading the file.

**So, what did I do wrong here?** How do I download the file via the Python script?

Answer (score 2):

Surround the `url` with quotes (`"`) when making the `curl` request.

```
os.system('curl "'+ url + '"')
```

To save it in a file, use

```
os.system('curl -o /tmp/file.txt "'+ url + '"')
```

Or, Use the `requests` module to make the `GET`

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url)
```